# Why CSS and JS files are not loaded when using IP address instead of localhost

Tags: php, codeigniter

I just installed Apache2 and MySQL on Ubuntu on my laptop. I am using CodeIgniter for my PHP project, everything is working when I use `localhost` in address bar.

But when I use the IP address of my laptop it works but without CSS and JS, which are not loaded. mod_rewrite is enabled, and .htaccess is working well. I am using base_url() for reference.

```
    <style type="text/css" src="<?=base_url()?>css/validate/screen.css"></style>
```

and base_url in config file is empty:

```
    $config['base_url']='';
```

I am badly stuck right here.

Comment: Why would you want it to work with ip address? Just curious. please include an example of what HTML is generated there.

Comment: i just wanna use the system as server for other systems in lan network

Comment: You could also skip the annoying IP part and edit `/etc/hosts` to include: `192.x.x.x   laptopserver` or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

And also your base_url should be given like

```
 $config['base_url']='http://MYIP/PROJ_FOLDER/';
```

and then try like

```
<style type="text/css" src="<?php echo base_url();?>css/validate/screen.css"></style>
```

Comment: @alipanahi I advice placing it in a project folder. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$config['base_url']='localhost';
```